# Mongodb find query returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im trying to get a product by its code id, but the result its empty array.
My controller:

```
 export const getProductByPLU = async (req, res) => {
  const  searchPLU  = req.query;
     try {
        const product = await Product.find({ Code: { $eq: searchPLU } });
        res.json({ data: product });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
    };
```

if i try to get this `http://localhost:5000/products/search?3036` result is

```
> {
"data": []
}
```

> 

I get all the products, just cant get that one specific.
Simple Product:

```
   {
    "_id": "618a42e4801d324e3d84c16c",
    "ProductId": "868",
    "Name": "Aus Wagyu Flat WX5+",`enter code here`
     "Barcode": 2000000001630,
     "Code": 163,
     }
```

Comment: `/products/search?code=163 `, `const  searchPLU  = +req.query.code;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending the request like this `http://localhost:5000/products/search?3036`
your `req.query` will be `{ 3036: '' }`.

You need the URL param to be a key:value pair so the correct way to do it will be: `http://localhost:5000/products/search?id=3036`
this will produce `{ id: '3036' }`

then you'll be able to get the id value by using `req.query.id`

Comment: Thank you, that was it ! :)

Comment: Happy I could help. Would appreciate if you accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can form your query in different ways, using:

**The Query String:**

An example URL in the browser: `http://localhost:5000/api/library?bookid=546`

This is a URL with a [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). The `bookid=546` is the query string (and this comes after the `?`). And, the GET request:

```
app.get("/api/library", function(req, resp) {
    // req.query value will be { bookid: "5416" }
    const bookId = req.query.bookid
    // If bookId is a number in the database, first convert the bookId
    // value to a number; this is because request query param values
    // are of string type
    const bookIdNum = parseInt(bookId)
    const doc = collection.find({ bookId: bookIdNum })
    // ...
})
```

**The Request Params:**

[req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) says: The `req.params` property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route "parameters". For example, if you have the route `/user/:name`, then the "name" property is available as `req.params.name`.

An example URL in the browser: `http://localhost:5000/api/library/Mark Twain`

And, the GET request:

```
app.get("/api/library/:author", function(req, resp) {
    // req.params value will be { author: "Mark Twain" }
    const authorName = req.params.author
    // make the database call to retrieve the book info using the authorName...
})
```