# How can I get all the field data based on a value in mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What im trying to do is to get all the information that a user has, based on one parameter whose key and value is `createdBy: phoneNumber`.
First I thought to put in the request body the phone number, and to use the `find()` method to find all the data in the database based on that phone number, but I found out that the get methods don't accept a request body.

```
exports.getLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const getLocation = await Location.find( req.params.createdBy )

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        msg: "Getting all the locations of the user",
        data: getLocation
    })
})
```

route

```
 /**
 * @swagger
 * /location/getLocation:
 *   get:
 *     summary: getting the location of the user by phone number
 *     tags: [Location]
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: false
 *       content:
 *        application/json:
 *          schema:
 *            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Location'
 *
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: the location has been recivied
 *       500:
 *         description: Some server error
 */
  router.get("/getLocation", getLocation)
```

How can I get all the data from the db by putting a value as a request?

Comment: why do you need `asyncHandler`

Comment: how does your route looks like?

Comment: You need to specify the `createdBy` parameter in the route URL. This gets accessed in your code as you had posted - `req.params.createdBy`.

Comment: @prasad_  do i need to put ```createdBy``` as a a req.body ?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906670/mongodb-find-query-returns-empty-array/69908347#69908347

Comment: @prasad_ my question is where do I put the phone number as a request to get the data from that phone number. Im testing with swagger.

Answer (score 0):

You dont even send an param. To send an param you need to do following:

```
router.get("/getLocation/:createdBy", getLocation)
```

Then you need to make an request like: `http://example.com/getLocation/somedata`

`req.params.createdBy` will be then `somedata`

Comment: cannot make a request url, bc im testing for react-native

Comment: @mier23 how do you make requests?

Comment: I make a request using swagger request body, I put a parameter and I execute the api